# Rails smtp issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, centos, smtp

I am junior rails developer.
I trying to send email via smtp of gmail.com
i found [this article](https://medium.com/@ericschwartz7/rails-mailer-tutorial-82700f6737d9) in internet.
my `environments/production.rb`

```
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :sendmail
  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
  config.action_mailer.default_options = {from: 'pangodfather@gmail.com'}

  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
      address:              'smtp.gmail.com',
      port:                 587,
      domain:               'devb.carwash.it',
      user_name:            'myaccount@gmail.com',
      password:             'mypass',
      authentication:       'plain',
      enable_starttls_auto: true
  }
```

Like this I trying to send mail

```
   UserNotificationMailer.send_change_password_link(@user, params[:user][:password]).deliver_now
```

I have this error. 
    Net::SMTPSyntaxError (501 Syntax: HELO hostname

On my server if I run `hostname`
hostname, output is :

```
devb.carwash.it
```

What I do wrong? 
Thanks

Comment: Try setting domain with `gmail.com` instead `devb.carwash.it`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so unfortunately I have no fix for this problem.
My fix is don't use mail() of action mailer, but use Mail gem - it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Domain should be `gmail.com` you have set it to your own domain but that's incorrect.

[From Ruby docs](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/net/smtp/rdoc/Net/SMTP.html#class-Net::SMTP-label-HELO+domain):

> HELO domain
>
> In almost all situations, you must provide a third argument to
>   ::start/SMTP#start. This is the domain name which you are on (the host
>   to send mail from). It is called the “HELO domain”. The SMTP server
>   will judge whether it should send or reject the SMTP session by
>   inspecting the HELO domain.

Example config:

```
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
      address:              'smtp.gmail.com',
      port:                 587,
      domain:               'gmail.com',
      user_name:            'myaccount@gmail.com',
      password:             'mypass',
      authentication:       :plain,
      enable_starttls_auto: true
  }
```

Comment: Error messages?

Comment: it's the same :(

Comment: Okay a few things. Are you testing in production? If not, you should move this to development.rb. Secondly, I need a lot more info from you. Edit your post with logs from your most recent attempts and changes to the code.

Comment: ok so I just testing send mail via smtp from command line and this work fine.
how I can get more info about error?

Comment: sure, I do test on production

Comment: Boris, you're cracking me up. This is killing me. Please don't test your applications in production. That was a question, not a request. You should move your SMTP configurations into `environments/development.rb` while you're developing this feature. Then, when you move to production, you'll want to mirror your SMTP configuration in the `production.rb` with your production creds.

Comment: you are right, but my smtp server has no authentication, this server receive from specific ip address, so I have no way to test it on dev. If I want to use no google smtp for example.
now I try to test on dev with google smtp

Comment: on dev error is the same 
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 542ms (ActiveRecord: 26.9ms)


  
Net::SMTPSyntaxError (501 Syntax: HELO hostname
):

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190926/discussion-between-veridian-dynamics-and-boris-kuzevanov).

Answer (score 0):

Let me share you what problems I faced while fixing this issue with Gmail..

1. Firstly **enable Less secure apps** login to Gmail.

   visit your [gmail settings](https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps) and enable less secure apps to get the application working.
2. **Change the value** of :authentication key from `:plain` to `:login`
3. IF you have **enabled 2-Step Verification** for accessing Gmail,you must need to give permission to you app.

Hope this helps :)